# Application Insights Delay?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I've looked in *many* places for details around the delay of time it takes for Application Insights data to appear in my dashboard, but can't find it documented anywhere.

I spent some time yesterday trying to debug an issue around my code seemingly unable to send data to application insights, only for the data to appear sometime later (~40 mins).

Does anybody have any details regarding time I should expect to have to wait prior to seeing data on my dashboard?

I've read a few FAQs an articles such as: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-troubleshoot-faq/ but am none the wiser.

More specifically, these were attempts to track exceptions and custom events.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Generally raw examples of your data should be available within couple of minutes from the time you send it, and aggregated data takes about 5-10 minutes to appear. Also when we are experiencing a processing delay we display a banner on the Overview page in Application Insights in the portal as on the screenshot below.
[image]

If you saw 40 minutes delay seeing your data this was either the case of ongoing issue with the processing pipeline, in which case a message should have been shown (and if not, it is a detection problem on our side), or, as we are often seeing, there could have been a configuration problem with your application that was later addressed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Since I'm using a persistence channel it could well be a configuration issue on my side. Although I've not made any changes to settings and I've tried to explicitly `Flush` and it made no difference. What you're saying, though, has answered my question directly so I'll make it accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: Just FYI: In case of custom metrics and properties there is a few hours delay.

Comment: I am also facing the delay issue. How can I resolve it?

Comment: A bit of a shame as it necessitates a second solution for the real-time logging that is required for debugging.

Comment: I'm too facing the same issue. The Log entries appears on the Search screens after 3-5 minutes delay. Due to this we need to tweak our code and I don't think it is a good way.

Comment: At the time of this writing, my logs are exactly 30 min delayed (and growing) and no banners or anything else displayed

Comment: I am seeing at least 40 minutes or more delay to get the logs to appear in app insights. which makes it useless

Comment: [Customer] "Your website is showing me an error" [Support] "Please wait 5 minutes while I wait for the logs to show me the problem"

Answer (score 4):

Agree with the comments in the accepted answer that real-time logging is a absolute requirement of an enterprise system.  Even the Portal says the following on the Monitor section of the Azure Functions blade:

[image]

This appears to be due to metric aggregation.  However I've just been shown Application Insights' [Live Metrics Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream) by a colleague.  It has **1-second latency**, which is probably what most readers of this question are after and thought worth sharing.